# JFrame shows up empty on Java Swing GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

The book that I am using says that this code should display the frame, and inside the frame a list and at least the OK button.  
When I compile, I only see the Frame with the frame name 'Event Object'.
Inside the frame is blank.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class EventObject extends JFrame
{
    private JList list;
    private DefaultListModel model;

    public EventObject()
    {
        setTitle("Event Object");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);

        model = new DefaultListModel();
        list = new JList(model);
        list.setBounds(150, 30, 220, 150);
        JButton ok = new JButton("Ok");
        ok.setBounds(30, 35, 80, 25);
        ok.addActionListener( new ActionListener () 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
                Date date = new Date();
                String s = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale).format(date);
                if ( !model.isEmpty() )
                    model.clear();
                    if (event.getID() == ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED)
                        model.addElement(" Event Id: ACTION_PERFORMED");
                    model.addElement(" Time: " + s);
                    String source = event.getSource().getClass().getName();
                    model.addElement(" Source: " + source);
                    int mod = event.getModifiers();
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(" Modifiers: ");
                    if ((mod & ActionEvent.ALT_MASK) > 0)
                        buffer.append("Alt ");
                    if ((mod & ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK) > 0)
                        buffer.append("Shift ");
                    if ((mod & ActionEvent.META_MASK) > 0)
                        buffer.append("Meta ");
                    if ((mod & ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK) > 0)
                        buffer.append("Ctrl ");
                    model.addElement(buffer);
                }
        });
        panel.add(ok);
        panel.add(list);

        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        new EventObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: You forgot to add `panel` to the `JFrame`.

Answer (score 3):

It it because you only created some components but didn't add anything to your `EventObject`(which extends JFrame). Try to add:

```
add(panel);
```

before `.setSize()` for example, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it should work.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class EventObject extends JFrame
{
private JList list;
private DefaultListModel model;

public EventObject()
{
    setTitle("Event Object");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    add(panel);

    model = new DefaultListModel();
    list = new JList(model);
    list.setBounds(150, 30, 220, 150);
    JButton ok = new JButton("Ok");
    ok.setBounds(30, 35, 80, 25);
    ok.addActionListener( new ActionListener () 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
            Date date = new Date();
            String s = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale).format(date);
            if ( !model.isEmpty() )
                model.clear();
                if (event.getID() == ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED)
                    model.addElement(" Event Id: ACTION_PERFORMED");
                model.addElement(" Time: " + s);
                String source = event.getSource().getClass().getName();
                model.addElement(" Source: " + source);
                int mod = event.getModifiers();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(" Modifiers: ");
                if ((mod & ActionEvent.ALT_MASK) > 0)
                    buffer.append("Alt ");
                if ((mod & ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK) > 0)
                    buffer.append("Shift ");
                if ((mod & ActionEvent.META_MASK) > 0)
                    buffer.append("Meta ");
                if ((mod & ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK) > 0)
                    buffer.append("Ctrl ");
                model.addElement(buffer);
            }
    });
    panel.add(ok);
    panel.add(list);

    setSize(500, 500);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    new EventObject();
}
}
```